# Order of elements in a commutative/abelian group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $(G, ◦)$ is a (not necessarily finite) commutative group, and if $g$ and $g'$ are members of $G$ which have finite orders (say $ω$ and $ω'$ respectively), then $g ◦ g'$is of finite order.
What is that order?

I've been looking online for some help with this but most places say that you can't really say too much about the order of the product of two finite order elements.  So I'm confused as to whether I can actually give an answer to this question.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. $(g ◦ g')^n = g^n ◦ (g')^n = 1$. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'll call $h=g'$, $z=w'$.

You want to find $n$ such that $g^nh^n=1$. Note that if $n$ is a multiple of $w$ and of $z$ then $g^nh^n=1\cdot 1=1$, so the order of $gh$ is at most $n$. In fact, it divides $n$.

Nothing more can be said. Consider the additive group $\Bbb Z_3={0,1,2}$, $g=1$, $h=2$. Then $z=w=3$ but the order of $g+h$ is $1$.